# Как обновить текстовый виджет в tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, виджет, label

Как обновить виджет в `tkinter` по нажатию кнопки и без нее? Много где искал, но ничего понятного не нашел.

Пожалуйста, приведите пример обновления виджета `label`. Желательно чтобы код был как можно более лаконичный.

Мой текущий код:

```
w = Tk()
urltime = 'https://какойто айпи'
req = requests.get(urltime)
b1 = bs(req.text,'lxml')
timenow = b1.find(class_="time-city-time-value").text
timelabel = Label(w,textvariable=timenow,font=('Cambria',20,'bold','normal'))
timelabel.grid(column=0,row=0)
w.maniloop()
```

Как сделать так, чтобы `timelabel` обновлялся?

Comment: label.configure(text=new_text)

Comment: @splash58 Ничего не обновляется

Comment: `label = Label(text='что-нибудь')`  а потом label.configure(text='что-то другое')

Comment: Все стоит на месте. Добавил код

Answer (score 1):

1. У вас опечатка в названии метода `mainloop`: `maniloop`
2. Параметр `textvariable` нужен для привязки объекта `StringVar` к виджету. Если просто нужно установить текст, используйте параметр `text`:

   ```
   w = Tk()
   timenow = "00:00:00"
   timelabel = Label(w,text=timenow,font=('Cambria',20,'bold','normal'))
   timelabel.grid(column=0,row=0)
   w.maniloop()
   ```
3. Если нужно изменить текст уже после создания, нужно менять свойство `text` с помощью метода `configure`, или менять через "ключ":

   ```
   w = Tk()

   timelabel = Label(w, font=('Cambria',20,'bold','normal'))
   timelabel.grid(column=0,row=0)

   def set_time():
       timenow = "00:00:00"
       timelabel.config(text=timenow)
       # Или:
       # timelabel["text"] = timenow

   Button(w, text="Set time", command=set_time).grid()
   w.mainloop()
   ```
4. Вариант с использованием параметра `textvariable` и `StringVar`:

   ```
   w = Tk()

   text_var = StringVar()
   timelabel = Label(w, textvariable=text_var, font=('Cambria',20,'bold','normal'))
   timelabel.grid(column=0,row=0)

   def set_time():
       timenow = "00:00:00"
       text_var.set(timenow)

   Button(w, text="Set time", command=set_time).grid()
   w.mainloop()
   ```